# Socket File System vs Regular Disk File System

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets, unix

When a socket is created it immediately creates a fake file for read/write data across the network but what exactly is this 'file'? A regular disk file would be located in the disk and anything would be written there but where does the socket file write to, a stream of bytes in memory perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

A socket does not create a "fake file".

It creates a *file descriptor*, which is a system abstraction for a stream (well, you tagged windows and linux, implementations are very system dependent). Files, Sockets, Pipes are classic Unix streams examples.

For a socket stream, bytes will be eventually physically written to hardware (memory and/or network card), for a file stream, bytes will be physically written to a physical drive.